# Store value in hidden field then pass it to email submission via query string

Tags: jquery, asp.net, forms, checkbox, hidden-field

I have some jQuery code that is meant to grab user input from a form and place it in the body of an email message. One of the fields in this form is an optional checkbox with an id and name of "member." I have a hidden field (called "memberChk") that is meant to store a value based on whether the checkbox is checked or not. If the checkbox is checked, then the hidden field should store a string value of "Yes." If the checkbox is not checked, then the hidden field should store "No."

Ok, I updated the jQuery code and now the value is always "No" regardless of whether the checkbox is checked or not. When the checkbox is checked, it should be displaying a "Yes" in the email. What am I missing?

This is the code for the checkbox and the hidden field:

```
<tr><td  colspan="3" valign="top"><input type="checkbox" id="member" name="member" value="Member of the NDGAA, PCSA, or Pet Professional Guild" /> Check if a you are a member of the NDGAA, PCSA, or Pet Professional Guild</td><asp:HiddenField ID="memberChk" runat="server" /></tr>
```

This is the jQuery code that is meant to set the value of the hidden field:

```
var member =  $('#memberChk').val();
    member = $('input[name="member"]:checked').size() == 0 ? "No" : "Yes";
```

And this is the part of the code where the query string is being built that is used to pass in the form entries to an email submission:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Usercontrols/forms/getaquote_processor.aspx",
        data: "FirstName=" + FirstName + "&LastName=" + LastName + "&Email=" + Email + "&Telephone=" + Telephone + "&BusinessName=" + BusinessName + 
            "&Address1=" + Address1 + "&Address2=" + Address2 + "&City=" + City + "&State=" + State + "&ZipCode=" + ZipCode + "&BusinessType=" + BusinessType +
            "&OwnershipType=" + OwnershipType + "&PartnershipName=" + PartnershipName + "&MemberOf=" + MemberOf + "&CurrentInsurance=" + CurrentInsurance +
            "&PolicyExpiration=" + PolicyExpiration + "&AnnualReceipts=" + AnnualReceipts + "&AnnualPayroll=" + AnnualPayroll + "&OwnOrRent=" + OwnOrRent +
            "&ConstructionType=" + ConstructionType + "&YearBuilt=" + YearBuilt + "&BuildingUpdates=" + BuildingUpdates + "&Heating=" + Heating + "&HeatingYear=" + HeatingYear + 
            "&Cooling=" + Cooling + "&CoolingYear=" + CoolingYear + "&Plumbing=" + Plumbing + "&PlumbingYear=" + PlumbingYear + "&Electrical=" + Electrical + "&ElectricalYear=" + ElectricalYear + 
            "&Roofing=" + Roofing + "&RoofingYear=" + RoofingYear + "&Sprinklers=" + Sprinklers + "&PlateGlass=" + PlateGlass +
            "&PlateGlassWidth=" + PlateGlassWidth + "&HomeBusiness=" + HomeBusiness + "&SeperateBuilding=" + SeperateBuilding + "&CostToReplaceBuilding=" + CostToReplaceBuilding +
            "&CostToReplaceContents=" + CostToReplaceContents + "&OwnersCostToReplaceBuilding=" + OwnersCostToReplaceBuilding + "&OwnersSquareFootage=" + OwnersSquareFootage +
            "&NumberOfEmployees=" + NumberOfEmployees + "&NumberOfContractors=" + NumberOfContractors + "&MAddress1=" + MAddress1 + "&MAddress2=" + MAddress2 + "&MCity=" + MCity + 
            "&MState=" + MState + "&MZipCode=" + MZipCode  + "&VehicleMake=" + VehicleMake + "&VehicleModel=" + Model + "&VIN=" + VIN + "&Cab=" + Cab + "&Customization=" + Customization + 
            "&LeaseCompany=" + LeaseCompany + "&DriversName=" + DriversName + "&DriversLicense=" + DriversLicense + "&Birthday=" + BirthDay + "&CageFree=" + CageFree + 
            "&ConstuctionOfRuns=" + ConstructionOfRuns + "&Floors=" + Floors + "&Walls=" + Walls + "&MaxDogs=" + MaxDogs + "&AvgDogs=" + AvgDogs + "&KennelsEnclosed=" + KennelsEnclosed + 
            "&KennelsHeated=" + KennelsHeated + "&FenceNeeded=" + FenceNeeded + "&IsFenceAttached=" + IsFenceAttached + "&FenceReplacementCost=" + FenceReplacementCost + 
            "&FenceSquareFeet=" + FenceSquareFeet + "&RequireVaccinations=" + RequireVaccinations + "&CustomersUnsupervised=" + CustomersUnsupervised + "&Member=" + member + "&Comments=" + comments,
```

Last but not least, the part of the email body that is meant to display the checkbox value in the email:

```
 #region MEMBERSHIP
        //MEMBERSHIP
        String Member = string.Empty;
        Member = Request.QueryString["Member"];
 #endregion MEMBERSHIP

  #region MEMBERSHIP
        sb.Append("<tr><td colspan=\"2\"><strong>Check if a you are a member of the NDGAA, PCSA, or Pet Professional Guild</strong></td></tr>");
        sb.Append(string.Format("<tr><td colspan=\"2\">{0}</td></tr>", Member));
  #endregion
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below

```
// work out the value
var checkVal = $('input[name="member"]:checked').length === 0 ? "No" : "Yes";

// get the checkbox
var member =  $('#memberChk');

// set the checkbox value
member.val(checkVal);
```

The issue is now though, that you are not letting ASP.NET post the form back so the hidden field is not being used the way it was meant to be so we need to get its value.

```
var memberVal =  member.val();
// obviously this step is not required you could just use the raw value we calculate above, 
// this is added as I don't know the execution flow of your code
```

The other way would be to use an onChange handler like in the JSBin I setup below in the comments

```
$('input[name="member"]').on('change', function(e)
{
  var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
  $('#memberChk').val(isChecked ? "Yes" : "No");
});

// then just get the value when you need it like
var member =  $('#memberChk').val();
```

Also did you know you can use $('form').serialize() [ http://api.jquery.com/serialize/ ] to get all your form values for the ajax call, this requires they all have a name attribute though?

Comment: I will try this...as for the $('form').serialize() method, I did not know about that, but this is also not my code. I don't know why the previous developer did not do it that way....

Comment: Ok, I did try your code and it works but when the checkbox is checked, the email submission still shows "no" as the response.

Comment: I have created a JSBin here http://jsbin.com/tazafiqejado/1/edit to demonstrate the checking of the checkbox.

Comment: I figured it out--your method worked. I had a typo I was not catching.